# Select Only first two line of a text block

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `VARCHAR` column where data is in this format:

```
John 
Smit
Big Street 26
London
England
```

This in one column, not  5, so I need to select only first two lines:

```
John
Smit
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This is in 5 rows or only 1?

Comment: This is only a row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the substring up to the second newline character:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(address, 1, INSTR(address, CHR(10), 1, 2) - 1) AS name
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (address) AS
SELECT 'John 
Smit
Big Street 26
London
England' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | NAME |
> | --- |
> | John Smit |

Answer (score 2):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT 
     REGEXP_SUBSTR ( YOURCOLUMN, '(\S*)(\s)'  , 1 , 1 ) || REGEXP_SUBSTR ( YOURCOLUMN, '(\S*)(\s)' , 1 , 2 ) as result
FROM YOURTABLE;
```

You can check the result [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ab08df62248630bbd4c50c29a0b0735f):

Comment: This does not always return what you expect it to return as the delimiting character is not a space [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=44205f47014521c026de21e33597dc06)